# python seaborn lib throwing error on import

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am loading missingno  lib on python as provided below.
while loading , it throws error at seaborn/rcmod.py.

following are the versions,-
missingno-0.3.8
numpy-1.9.0
matplotlib-1.5.0
seaborn==0.8.1

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 05:13:40)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import missingno as mn
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/missingno/__init__.py", line 1, in 
<module>
from .missingno import matrix
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/missingno/missingno.py", line 6, in 
<module>
import seaborn as sns
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/seaborn/__init__.py", line 6, in 
<module>
from .rcmod import *
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/seaborn/rcmod.py", line 161
style_dict = {k: mpl.rcParams[k] for k in _style_keys}
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`seaborn` doesn't support Python 2.6: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/88c49ef6c14ca69def8195f03d467915b3b0597c/setup.py#L82

You need to update your Python to at least Python 2.7 to use `seaborn`.